# Reducing the brightness of an LED Strip (Adafruit Dotstar RGB Strip) using Python

Tags: python, debugging, raspberry-pi, led

I have this code below piping data to a strip of RGB LEDs.  The code works fine.  The Adafruit Dotstar libray (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_DotStar) also has a strandtest.py example in addition to the code below.  In the test example it is possible to reduce the brightness of the LEDs using *strip.setBrightnes(2)*.  I have duplicated that code in the same general location in the code below but it does not change the LED brightness.  I suspect a bug with in the library but I would still like to find a solution to reduce the LED brightness.  I am at wits end (read NOOB).
Any help reducing the LED brightness is appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import PIL
from PIL import Image
from dotstar import Adafruit_DotStar
filename  = "/home/pi/Adafruit_DotStar_Pi/marilynlowerres.jpg"

datapin   = 10
clockpin  = 11
strip     = Adafruit_DotStar(0, datapin, clockpin)

rOffset = 3
gOffset = 2
bOffset = 1
strip.begin()
strip.setBrightness(2)
print "Loading..."
img = Image.open(filename).convert("RGB")
pixels = img.load()
width = img.size[0]
height = img.size[1]
print "%dx%d pixels" % img.size
gamma = bytearray(256)
for i in range(256):
    gamma[i] = int(pow(float(i) / 255.0, 2.7) * 255.0 + 0.5)
print "Allocating..."
column = [0 for x in range(width)]
for x in range(width):
    column[x] = bytearray(height * 4)
print "Converting..."
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
    value= pixels[x, y]
    y4= y * 4 
    column[x][y4]= 0xFF
    column[x][y4 + rOffset] = gamma[value[0]]
    column[x][y4 + gOffset] = gamma[value[1]] 
    column[x][y4 + bOffset] = gamma[value[2]]
print "Displaying..."
while True:
    for x in range(width):
        strip.show(column[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to reducing pixel brightness provided by Adafruit Industries.  Thanks Adafruit!

```
  column[x][y4 + rOffset] = gamma[value[0]/2] # Gamma-corrected R
  column[x][y4 + gOffset] = gamma[value[1]/2] # Gamma-corrected G
  column[x][y4 + bOffset] = gamma[value[2]/2] # Gamma-corrected B
```

Answer (score 0):

I think setBrightness only has effect when using the library methods such as strip.setPixelColor. When you are using strip.show(array) you are responsible for setting the brightness.

You could keep the gamma curve and shift the value down based on a brightness value. Let's have brightness range from 0-255 as in setBrightness. This function color_adjust will keep the values following the gamma just offset by the brightness value, and clamp them in the range 0-255.

```
def color_adjust(x, brightness, gamma):
    def clamp(value, low, high):
        return max(low, min(value, high))
    return gamma[clamp(x-(255-brightness), 0, 255)]

column[x][y4 + rOffset] = color_adjust(value[0], brightness, gamma)
column[x][y4 + gOffset] = color_adjust(value[1], brightness, gamma)
column[x][y4 + bOffset] = color_adjust(value[2], brightness, gamma)
```